# can anybody help me to provide SQL as per my request

Tags: sql, oracle11g, group-by

```
select created_date,count(*) tot 
from smart_meters_t 
group by created_date 
order by created_date;
```

This code I want in Oracle Langauage.Please anyone help on this will be greatly helpful.

```
created_date  tot 
12/01/2019    148
06/02/2019    1
28/02/2019    48
```

I need data like below

```
 created_date  tot 
    12/01/2019   148
    13/01/2019   148
    14/01/2019   148
    .
    .
    .
    .
    05/01/2019   148
    06/02/2019    1
    07/02/2019    1
    08/02/2019    1
    09/02/2019    1
    .
    .
    .
    .
    27/02/2019    1
    28/02/2019    48
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a series of dates using:

```
select date '2019-01-02' + level
from dual
connect by date '2019-01-01' + level < date '2019-02-28'
```

Then the rest could be done with `left join` and `lag()`:

```
with dates as (
      select (date '2019-01-02' + level) as dte
      from dual
      connect by date '2019-01-01' + level < date '2019-02-28'
     )
select d.dte,
       coalesce(t.tot,
                lag(t.tot ignore nulls) over (order by d.dte)
               ) as tot
from dates d left join
     t
     on d.dte = t.created_date
order by d.dte;
```

Comment: we should not provide date as static ,,it should be calculated as per the data and date of records generated

Comment: @venkivenkat - well it's easy enough to edit the WITH clause subquery to use `min()` and `max()` dates from your table instead of hardcoded values.

Comment: Can you provide me query according to my question ,,I am unable to place columns and tables in your query from my table